# Non parametric Inverse (cumulative) distribution functions

Tags: r, statistics, kernel

I'm working with kernel estimation, I apply the `density` function from R to my data file (bivariate), after a couple of statistical treatments I need to transform this data and here comes my problem:

Is there a function of the inverse cumulative distribution with a non parametric method?

I have tried Google, ethz forums, R help but it seems to be missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [quantile](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/quantile.html) function:

```
# simulate some data
mydata = rnorm(1000)

# print the quantiles at a few points
# (it's the inverse of the cumulative distribution function):
print(quantile(mydata, .5))
print(quantile(mydata, .75))

# show the curve from 0 to 1
curve(quantile(mydata, x))
```

Comment: Just to clarify: 'quantile' is the inverse function of 'density' (in a non parametric sense) ?

Comment: Do you mean cumulative density? Then yes. Try `curve(ecdf(mydata)(x), from=-3, to=3)` and you'll see it's the inverse.

Comment: I have tried to implement your advice, but it seems that I exposed myself wrong.

`Estimated_data = density(Original,bw=sj,kernel="epanechnikov") quantile(Estimated_data, .95)` 
This would give me the value of the accumulated 95% in the Estimated_data and not in the "Original"

Comment: `density` does *not* give you the cumulative density- did you mean something else in your question and title? (You specifically asked for the "inverse cumulative distribution").

Comment: The original data has been estimated by kernel (that is the reason I  wrote `density`).  For this reason by using quantile will give me the inverse of the cumulative distribution.In the title I also refer "Non parametric", regarding to this is that I don't know the original distribution of the data.

Comment: In this part I explain in a plain way what I'm referring to [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446569/inverse-function-of-an-unknown-cumulative-function/14446659#14446659