# Inverse function of an unknown cumulative function

Tags: r, statistics, kernel, quantile

I'm working with a data file, the observations inside are random values. In this case I don't know the distribution of x (my observations). I'm using the function density in order to estimate the density, because I must apply a kernel estimation.

```
T=density(datafile[,1],bw=sj,kernel="epanechnikov")
```

After this I must integrate this because I'm looking for a quantile (similar to VaR, 95%).
For this I have 2 options:

```
ecdf()
quantile()
```

Now I have the value of the quantile 95, but this is the data estimated by kernel.

**Is there a function which I can use to know the value of the quantile 95 of the original data?**

I remark that this is a distribution unknown, for this I would like to imagine a non parametric method as Newton, like the one that is in SAS `solve()`

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`quantile()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/quantile.html) for this. Here is an example using random data:

```
> data<-runif(1000)

> q<-quantile(data, .95)
> q
      95% 
0.9450324
```

Here, the data is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1, so the 95th percentile is close to 0.95.

To perform the inverse transformation:

```
> ecdf(data)(q)
[1] 0.95
```

Comment: But quantile will give me the value of the last estimated data and a I'm looking for the original.
Remember that the data have been estimated by kernel.

`Estimated_data = density(Original,bw=sj,kernel="epanechnikov")
quantile(Estimated_data, .95)`

This would give me the value of the accumulated 95% in the Estimated_data and not in the "Original".

Comment: @user1970451: In my example, `data` refers to your original data.

Comment: Yes data referes to the original data, but the quantile have been calculated over `runif(1000)` and the quantile 0.95 will be near 95% in this case the vale is 0.94 but this value correspond to the transformed data, my question was if there is a way to find the inverse of this in order to obtain the value that 0.94 may refer in the original data.

Comment: @user1970451: Are you looking for `ecdf(original_data)(q)`? See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: I'm looking for the inverse of ecdf.

Comment: `quantile` IS the inverse of `ecdf`.

Comment: I think we're running in circles.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if this is on any relevance for you anymore...
However I think what may be helpful to the answer above

```
data <- rnorm(1000)

my_ecdf <- ecdf(data)

my_ecdf_inv <- function(x) {quantile(data, x)}

my_ecdf_inv(my_ecdf(2))

x <- seq(-3, 3, 0.1)
plot(x, sapply(sapply(x, my_ecdf),my_ecdf_inv))
```